# Select data where have DateTime from some minute ago until now?

Tags: mysql, datetime

I will ask how query about Select data where having DateTime from some minute ago until now ?
ex : i will get result data from 5 minute ago (field: input_time) until now ..

this is my query

```
SELECT *
FROM
operasi
WHERE 
TIMESTAMP(input_time) <= TIMESTAMP(now()) 
AND 
ORDER BY input_time DESC LIMIT 0,10
```

Comment: Missing a space here `input_timeDESC`

Comment: Have you got any error and what you want?

Comment: oh thanks, please check again :)

Comment: ex : i will get result data from 5 minute ago (field: input_time) until now , sir ...

Answer (score 0):

You should do the query as:

```
SELECT *
FROM operasi
WHERE input_time <= now() and
      input_time >= date_sub(now(), interval 5 minute)
ORDER BY input_time DESC
LIMIT 0, 10;
```

This structure will allow the query to take advantage of an index on `input_time`.  If you wrap the column in a function, then that is less likely.